# C++ - Re-implement map data structure

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am working on a large codebase. There is no support for the map data structure. Is there a list of efficient open source data structures I can implement into this codebase without adding any external dependencies?

Comment: Can you use an open source implementation of the C++ standard library?

Comment: or the [boost::container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container.html) library?

Comment: Where did you find a C++ compiler with no map data structure?

Comment: Actually, you should be more specific about what subset of C++ you have support for, because efficient open source data structure libraries tend to depend on the C++ standard library.

Comment: What are your reasons for limiting external dependencies? Is it size restraints, licensing issues, or otherwise? If it is licensing issues, some open source licenses are intent on keeping software open source, so depending on how you link with it inside your own codebase, it could impact whether or not your codebase becomes open source. Simply asking for open source solutions may not provide you with what you want without being more specific about your constraints.

Answer (score 3):

- **To look at somewhat contained implementation, see GNU STL Map:**

  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/stl__map_8h-source.html
- If you have access to Boost (It's open source), Boost has a [**map container**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_container_header_reference.html#header.boost.container.map_hpp). Boost is reasonably self contained, not sure if it suits your definition of "no external dependencies".
- Also, check [GLib collections](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/resources.html)

Comment: If it has any external dependencies or is part of a larger library, I am out of luck. Thanks though.

Comment: `boost` does not have any external dependencies.

Comment: @PladniusBrooks: Why can't it be part of a larger library?

Comment: @Massa "unfortunately", it depends on the C++ standard library, and OP seems to imply he does not have full access to that.

Comment: Fusion map is not a general purpose map and almost certainly not what the poster wants.

Comment: You probably want the [map from the boost container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_container_header_reference.html#header.boost.container.map_hpp).

Answer (score 1):

The best free map I know of is std::map.  Is there a reason you can't use this?